# how to use CloudFlare SSL in Laravel-websockets

Tags: laravel, cloudflare, pusher, laravel-websockets

my project hosted in digitalocean and I have connected domain to server using cloudflare.
I using SSL. But WSS connection does not work. I got this error message
`WebSocket connection to 'wss://mywebsite.com/app/ABCDEFG?protocol=7&client=js&version=6.0.3&flash=false' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`

I have apache2 server

my config/broadcasting.php looks like

```
'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'useTLS' => false,
            'encrypted'=>true,
            'host'=>'127.0.0.1',
            'port'=>2053,
            'scheme'=>'https',
            'curl_options'=> [
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

and client side 
bootstrap.js looks like

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: false,
    encrypted:true,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 2053,
    wssPort: 2053,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports:['ws','wss'],

});
```

and I running command `php artisan websockets:serve --port=2053`

if you want any additional information please write comment.
anyone have solution?
thanks

new error `failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.`

Comment: there is a SSL property in `websockets.php`. Did you assign your `CERTIFICATE_FILE` and `CERTIFICATE_KEY` to it? Post it here as well.

Comment: YES I already do that but same problem

Comment: Do you mind working with WS instead of WSS? Or you strongly prefer wss?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Apache Proxy Web Socket Tunnel module or Proxy Http module:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_http.html

When check connection and proxy pass it to WS backend:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) "ws://127.0.0.1:2053/$1" [P,L]
```